# Wrong type argument when using reftex-mode with master-file

Tags: emacs, auctex

I am using emacs on debian-12 with auctex and reftex. I am editing a buffer with the master-file variable set to one other file. Then when I try to insert an equation environment C-c C-e equation emacs I got the message:

`Wrong type argument: symbolp, #[128 "\300\301^B\"\207" [apply reftex-label reftex-label nil] 4 nil (advice-eval-interactive-spec (cadr (interactive-form 'reftex-label)))]`

Then the environment is created without the generated `\label{eq:***}`.

The same slave-file, the same master-file, and the same .emacs file in another machine running Ubuntu 22.04 does not catch the same error and the `\label{eq:**}` is generated smoothly.

Comment: Please don't post the same question to emacs.SE and StackOverflow. Choose one to keep and delete the other. Thx.

Comment: I am sorry for my misunderstanding. I have just delete the question posted to emacs.SE. Thx.

Comment: related: https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/auctex/2023-11/msg00019.html

Answer (score 0):

This issue was solved by removing the AUCTeX installation shipped with Debian 12 and re-installing AUCTeX via the emacs package-installer.

Details on:

https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/auctex/2023-11/msg00019.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/35273456)

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for my misunderstanding. I hope the amends fix this.